# Is Tobias' Latios the same Latios as the one in the Pokémon Heroes movie?

Tags: pokemon

How can Tobias in Sinnoh League Champions ep.658 own Latios? Latios, as a legendary Pokemon, appears only once in the whole Pokémon world and, for we all know, he is dead since the *Pokemon Heroes* movie?

Answer (score 3):

Although they are called "legendary", these Pokémon are not necessarily unique in the anime (or in the games). A good example is [Silver](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Silver_%28Johto%29), which is a younger Lugia. Tobias most likely has a second Latios.

Comment: I thought of that too, however Bulbapedia says that "Silver is a baby Lugia"...That would mean the other Latios would have to be the parent. But that was never mentioned, that's why I feel a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that Pokemon Heroes mentions that they come with their father and HE became the first soul dew. Not only that, but at the end, a Latias can be seen flying with two Latios, one her size and one larger. They could be another family, or perhaps the entire family reunited.